# How to run jmeter using linux command?

Tags: linux, jmeter

I have jmx file and i want to run jmeter from linux command. I am using RedHat linux. Currently i am using following command but its not working:

```
sh jmeter.sh -n -t test.jmx -l log.jtl
```

Comment: what is not working? do you get any errors?

Comment: What error are you getting after executing this command?

Comment: What's the error? It is easier to answer if error details are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check file name in command. Its a common  mistake. I was getting Could not open file error. Is so then please check file name is it test.jmx

Answer (score -1):

The command should be fine. Please double check that you have Java installed and it's version. It's recommended to use Oracle JDK 6+ to run JMeter tests.

So make sure that `java --version` command returns something like:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

use following command set to start clean (they assume that Java is installed to /opt/java and test.jmx file lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java && export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH && export PATH
./jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l log.jtl
```

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for more details.